# Procedural music generation?

Tags: procedural-music

Anyone have good book / article recommendation for procedural generation of background music? (No vocals, just instruments).

I'm not interested in:

```
How do I generate the sound of a particular note on a particular instrument
```

I'm interested in:

```
How do I generate the melody / score for the music.
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks for the reference to Brian Eno. I'm definitely looking into the ambient/user can ignore type of music. I.e. think the background music of a game. It's there to provide some basic mood, but the focus is the game.

Comment: If you're lucky, Brian Eno might read your post.  Otherwise,  could you give some more details about what kind of melady/score you are thinking about?   You can use something like csound for this, but it's not really an out-of-the-box kind of solution.  http://www.csounds.com/tutorials

Comment: It does sound more like music theory than programming, if that is what your after Brian Eno (as Joshua said) might be worth investigating, if not maybe elaborate your question a little bit more.

Comment: Just for fun: Check out "Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency", it has some references to music generation. And anything by Douglas Adams is a must-read for a programmer anyhow ;-).

Comment: While it's not procedural generation, if you want spacey music, just take any song and run it through Audacity's [Paulstretch](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Paulstretch) effect. It does a really nice job, and has very pleasing results. Here's [one example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9SvZHrnEDE).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometime ago I ran into [ChucK](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/), which is a programming-language to generate music/sound/audio:

> ChucK presents a new time-based, concurrent programming model that's highly precise and expressive (we call this strongly-timed), as well as dynamic control rates, and the ability to add and modify code on-the-fly. In addition, ChucK supports MIDI, OSC, HID device, and multi-channel audio. It's fun and easy to learn, and offers composers, researchers, and performers a powerful programming tool for building and experimenting with complex audio synthesis/analysis programs, and real-time interactive control.

I believe the end result can be converted into MIDI, which can then be converted into a score or sheet notation.

I don't know if this is what you're looking for. Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

After thinking about this a little longer, I think what you can possibly do (and this sounds a bit crazy) is write code that generates ChucK code. So define a set of rules for your music/score generation and then use that to create valid ChucK code. After you run the ChucK code, you can get a MIDI file which you can then convert into score/sheet-music.

Comment: +1 for hinting me to ChucK - interesting stuff (though I don't know if it helps the original questioner)

Answer (score 2):

The book "Computer Models of Musical Creativity" by David Cope should help you along with the theoretical side of computer-assisted composition, though you might want some music theory under your belt before you dive in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in procedural music check out the Condition30 site -- condition30.com
This music is all procedural.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in an implementation of procedural music based on cellular automata in C#, you could grab the source code from http://proceduralmidi.codeplex.com/. A binary is also available.